# How project Velodyne point clouds on image? (KITTI Dataset)

Tags: matlab, projection, camera-calibration, lidar

Here is my code to project Velodyne points into the images:

```Matlab
cam       = 2;
frame     = 20;

% compute projection matrix velodyne->image plane
R_cam_to_rect = eye(4);
[P, Tr_velo_to_cam, R] = readCalibration('D:/Shared/training/calib/',frame,cam)
R_cam_to_rect(1:3,1:3) = R;
P_velo_to_img = P*R_cam_to_rect*Tr_velo_to_cam;


% load and display image
img = imread(sprintf('D:/Shared/training/image_2/%06d.png',frame));
fig = figure('Position',[20 100 size(img,2) size(img,1)]); axes('Position',[0 0 1 1]);
imshow(img); hold on;

% load velodyne points
fid = fopen(sprintf('D:/Shared/training/velodyne/%06d.bin',frame),'rb');
velo = fread(fid,[4 inf],'single')';
% remove every 5th point for display speed
velo = velo(1:5:end,:); 
fclose(fid);

% remove all points behind image plane (approximation
idx = velo(:,1)<5;
velo(idx,:) = [];

% project to image plane (exclude luminance)
velo_img = project(velo(:,1:3),P_velo_to_img);

% plot points
cols = jet;
for i=1:size(velo_img,1)
col_idx = round(64*5/velo(i,1));
plot(velo_img(i,1),velo_img(i,2),'o','LineWidth',4,'MarkerSize',1,'Color',cols(col_idx,:));
```

where readCalibration function is defined as

```Matlab
function [P, Tr_velo_to_cam, R_cam_to_rect] = readCalibration(calib_dir,img_idx,cam)

% load 3x4 projection matrix
P = dlmread(sprintf('%s/%06d.txt',calib_dir,img_idx),' ',0,1);

Tr_velo_to_cam = P(6,:);
R_cam_to_rect = P(5,1:9);

P = P(cam+1,:);
P = reshape(P ,[4,3])';
Tr_velo_to_cam = reshape(Tr_velo_to_cam ,[3,4])';
R_cam_to_rect = reshape(R_cam_to_rect ,[3,3])';

end
```

But here is the result:

[image]

what is wrong with my code? I changed the "cam" variable from 0 to 3 and none of them worked. You can find a sample of Calibration file in this link: 
[How to understand KITTI camera calibration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407474/how-to-understand-kitti-camera-calibration-files)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by myself. here is the modification in readCalibration function:

```
Tr_velo_to_cam = P(6,:);
Tr_velo_to_cam = reshape(Tr_velo_to_cam ,[4,3])';
Tr_velo_to_cam = [Tr_velo_to_cam;0 0 0 1];
```