# Format of parameters in KITTI's calibration file

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, slam, slam-algorithm

I accessed calibration files from [part odometry of KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php), wherein contents of one calibration file are as follows:

```
P0: 7.188560000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 6.071928000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 7.188560000000e+02 1.852157000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 1.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00
P1: 7.188560000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 6.071928000000e+02 -3.861448000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 7.188560000000e+02 1.852157000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 1.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00
P2: 7.188560000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 6.071928000000e+02 4.538225000000e+01 0.000000000000e+00 7.188560000000e+02 1.852157000000e+02 -1.130887000000e-01 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 1.000000000000e+00 3.779761000000e-03
P3: 7.188560000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 6.071928000000e+02 -3.372877000000e+02 0.000000000000e+00 7.188560000000e+02 1.852157000000e+02 2.369057000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 0.000000000000e+00 1.000000000000e+00 4.915215000000e-03
Tr: 4.276802385584e-04 -9.999672484946e-01 -8.084491683471e-03 -1.198459927713e-02 -7.210626507497e-03 8.081198471645e-03 -9.999413164504e-01 -5.403984729748e-02 9.999738645903e-01 4.859485810390e-04 -7.206933692422e-03 -2.921968648686e-01
```

I can get that P0, P1 represent monochrome camera and P2, P3 color camera. To my understanding, common shape of camera intrinsic is

```
fx 0  cx
0  fy cy
0  0  1 .
```

So I cannot figure out the meaning of remaining three parameter (I guess used for distortion rectification) in each line and the last line following label `Tr`.

A similar question can be found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407474/how-to-understand-kitti-camera-calibration-files), but answers to it are still unobvious to me. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

In those files, `P1`, `P0` etc are not camera intrinsics but projection matrices, defined by something like

```
P1=calibration_matrix * [R_1 | T_1]
```

which means that they are of size `3*4`. I'm not exactly sure whether the corresponding definition is the one above or if you'll have to use (well, it's an equivalent definition, more or less...)

```
P1=calibration_matrix*[R_1.transpose() | -R_1.transpose()*T_1]
```

but I think that it's easy to check this by just reading/displaying the data.

As for `Tr`, it is the concatenation of all camera positions. You have four cameras `P0, ..., P3`, and `Tr` has `12` elements, so the first three are the translation of `P0`, the next three are the translation of `P1` and so on. What I'm not sure about is whether each of those are expressed as `T_i` or `-R_i.transpose()*T_i`. I think the safest way is try to check this by playing with the data.

As for why there are four cameras `P0, ...,P3`, to quote their [paper](http://www.mrt.kit.edu/z/publ/download/2013/GeigerAl2013IJRR.pdf):

*Here,
i
∈
{
0
,
1
,
2
,
3
}
is the camera index, where
0
represents
the left grayscale,
1
the right grayscale,
2
the left color and
3
the right color camera.*

I think that also explains why their projection matrices are close to each other.

Comment: But why the projection matrices keep constant after incorporating camera extrinsics (aka. rotation and translation). Or, each line only signifys projection matrix of the first frame?

Comment: These do not look constant to me... Look at the fourth column, or the last one.

Comment: Hi, my message is that each projection matrix in four should vary with each camera's ego-motion. In other words, every image corresponds to separate projection matrix.

Comment: In addition, all parameters are the same except for the fourth, eighth, twelfth column.

Comment: @Finley I edited the answer. In addition, I think it would be a good idea for you to go through the paper I linked to.

Answer (score -1):

Those are **baselines** in meters w.r.t. the reference camera 0.

This post has more details:
[How Kitti calibration matrix was calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918538/how-kitti-calibration-matrix-was-calculated)

Comment: Can you maybe extend your answer a little bit?