# kitti dataset camera projection matrix

Tags: computer-vision, projection, camera-calibration

I am looking at the kitti dataset and particularly how to convert a world point into the image coordinates. I looked at the README and it says below that I need to transform to camera coordinates first then multiply by the projection matrix. I have 2 questions, coming from a non computer vision background

1. I looked at the numbers from calib.txt and in particular the matrix is 3x4 with non-zero values in the last column. I always thought this matrix `= K[I|0]`, where K is the camera's intrinsic matrix. So, why is the last column non-zero and what does it mean? e.g P2 is

> ```
> array([[7.070912e+02, 0.000000e+00, 6.018873e+02, 4.688783e+01],
>        [0.000000e+00, 7.070912e+02, 1.831104e+02, 1.178601e-01],
>        [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00, 6.203223e-03]])
> ```

2. After applying projection into [u,v,w] and dividing u,v by w, are these values with respect to origin at the center of image or origin being at the top left of the image?

---

README:

> calib.txt: Calibration data for the cameras: P0/P1 are the 3x4
>   projection
>       matrices after rectification. Here P0 denotes the left and P1 denotes the
>       right camera. Tr transforms a point from velodyne coordinates into the
>       left rectified camera coordinate system. In order to map a point X from the
>       velodyne scanner to a point x in the i'th image plane, you thus have to
>       transform it like:
>
> ```
>   x = Pi * Tr * X
> ```

Comment: where you able to understand or solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Refs:

1. [How to understand the KITTI camera calibration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407474/how-to-understand-kitti-camera-calibration-files)
2. [Format of parameters in KITTI's calibration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210547/format-of-parameters-in-kittis-calibration-file)
3. http://www.cvlibs.net/publications/Geiger2013IJRR.pdf

Answer:

I strongly recommend you read those references above. They may solve most, if not all, of your questions.

For question 2: The projected points on images are with respect to origin at the top left. See ref 2 & 3, the coordinates of a far 3d point in image are (`center_x`, `center_y`), whose values are provided in the `P_rect` matrices. Or you can verify this with some simple codes:

```
import numpy as np
p = np.array([[7.070912e+02, 0.000000e+00, 6.018873e+02, 4.688783e+01],
              [0.000000e+00, 7.070912e+02, 1.831104e+02, 1.178601e-01],
              [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00, 6.203223e-03]])
x = [0, 0, 1E8, 1]  # A far 3D point
y = np.dot(p, x)
y[0] /= y[2]
y[1] /= y[2]
y = y[:2]
print(y)
```

You will see some output like:

```
array([6.018873e+02, 1.831104e+02 ])
```

which is quite near the `(p[0, 2], p[1, 2])`, a.k.a. (`center_x`, `center_y`).

Answer (score 2):

For all the P matrices (3x4), they represent:

```
P(i)rect = [[fu 0  cx  -fu*bx],
            [0  fv  cy -fv*by],
            [0   0   1  0]]
```

Last column are **baselines** in meters w.r.t. the reference camera 0. You can see the P0 has all zeros in the last column because it is the reference camera.

This post has more details:
[How Kitti calibration matrix was calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918538/how-kitti-calibration-matrix-was-calculated)