# Are Kitti 2015 stereo dataset images already rectified?

Tags: camera-calibration, stereo-3d, kitti

I am trying to test my Stereo matching algorithm on Kitti 2015 stereo dataset
http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_scene_flow.php?benchmark=stereo. My algorithm assumes that the stereo cameras are well calibrated and the stereo images already rectified.
Are the Kitti 2015 images already rectified ? or do I need to rectify them ? if yes how to do this in OpenCV using the info provided in the calibration file?

```
calib_time: 09-Jan-2012 13:57:47
corner_dist: 9.950000e-02
S_00: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_00: 9.842439e+02 0.000000e+00 6.900000e+02 0.000000e+00 9.808141e+02 2.331966e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_00: -3.728755e-01 2.037299e-01 2.219027e-03 1.383707e-03 -7.233722e-02
R_00: 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
T_00: 2.573699e-16 -1.059758e-16 1.614870e-16
S_rect_00: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_00: 9.999239e-01 9.837760e-03 -7.445048e-03 -9.869795e-03 9.999421e-01 -4.278459e-03 7.402527e-03 4.351614e-03 9.999631e-01
P_rect_00: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
S_01: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_01: 9.895267e+02 0.000000e+00 7.020000e+02 0.000000e+00 9.878386e+02 2.455590e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_01: -3.644661e-01 1.790019e-01 1.148107e-03 -6.298563e-04 -5.314062e-02
R_01: 9.993513e-01 1.860866e-02 -3.083487e-02 -1.887662e-02 9.997863e-01 -8.421873e-03 3.067156e-02 8.998467e-03 9.994890e-01
T_01: -5.370000e-01 4.822061e-03 -1.252488e-02
S_rect_01: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_01: 9.996878e-01 -8.976826e-03 2.331651e-02 8.876121e-03 9.999508e-01 4.418952e-03 -2.335503e-02 -4.210612e-03 9.997184e-01
P_rect_01: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 -3.875744e+02 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
S_02: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_02: 9.597910e+02 0.000000e+00 6.960217e+02 0.000000e+00 9.569251e+02 2.241806e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_02: -3.691481e-01 1.968681e-01 1.353473e-03 5.677587e-04 -6.770705e-02
R_02: 9.999758e-01 -5.267463e-03 -4.552439e-03 5.251945e-03 9.999804e-01 -3.413835e-03 4.570332e-03 3.389843e-03 9.999838e-01
T_02: 5.956621e-02 2.900141e-04 2.577209e-03
S_rect_02: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_02: 9.998817e-01 1.511453e-02 -2.841595e-03 -1.511724e-02 9.998853e-01 -9.338510e-04 2.827154e-03 9.766976e-04 9.999955e-01
P_rect_02: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 4.485728e+01 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 2.163791e-01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 2.745884e-03
S_03: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_03: 9.037596e+02 0.000000e+00 6.957519e+02 0.000000e+00 9.019653e+02 2.242509e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_03: -3.639558e-01 1.788651e-01 6.029694e-04 -3.922424e-04 -5.382460e-02
R_03: 9.995599e-01 1.699522e-02 -2.431313e-02 -1.704422e-02 9.998531e-01 -1.809756e-03 2.427880e-02 2.223358e-03 9.997028e-01
T_03: -4.731050e-01 5.551470e-03 -5.250882e-03
S_rect_03: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_03: 9.998321e-01 -7.193136e-03 1.685599e-02 7.232804e-03 9.999712e-01 -2.293585e-03 -1.683901e-02 2.415116e-03 9.998553e-01
P_rect_03: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 -3.395242e+02 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 2.199936e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 2.729905e-03
```

Comment: Yes, they are already rectified. See https://github.com/yanii/kitti-pcl/blob/master/KITTI_README.TXT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand the KITTI camera calibration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407474/how-to-understand-the-kitti-camera-calibration-files)

Comment: @decadenza, Thank your comment I found the answer to my question in this paper http://www.cvlibs.net/publications/Menze2018JPRS.pdf. In page 9 section 2, it is clearly evident that the images are synchronized and rectfied.